# Ways to extract images from pdf using R

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

Is there a way to extract images from pdf using R and save them into a folder?
there are a lot of similar questions regarding other programming languages and there is apparently a way to do this in python, was wondering if the same work can be replicated in r https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-pdf-images-in-python

there is pdftools package in r but does not sound like it can help much with images, only reads text and there is an option for ocr, I just want to extract the images and store them into a folder.

I can try to use `reticulate` package to use this python method in r but I won't be able to loop / map it as I would like. That's why I was asking if anyone knows a way in R.

thank you.

Comment: What about [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/rdrr.io/a/cran/metagear/src/R/PDF_extractImages.R)

Comment: @at80 thank you. could not install the package yet, will try on a different computer. but looks like it does exactly what I want plus many additional useful functions !

Comment: with the R package pdftools, you can use pdf_convert et and pdf_render_page. I use this at my job and it works very well to convert PDF pages to images

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
library(pdftools)
path_To_PDF <- "C:/my_pdf.pdf"
pdf_convert(path_To_PDF)
```